# New tabbar feature in browser app like ipad safari

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I want to create new tabs feature in my iPad browser app same as tabs in iPad safari.is there any control available?? is it possible to create custom easily?? or what are alternatives??

thanks to all of you for your upcoming answers

Comment: Uh... Image?  And what have you tried? I'll send you to the right control if you can at least prove to me that you didn't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Hi Due to my less reputation i was unable to upload image.and for now i have created a bar and on bar i have put a textfield.and on click of done button i have open the entered address in web view.so for one page every thing is fine but i want to know how to create multi page tab.PLease help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a tab view that comes pretty close to the one in Safari on iPad:

https://github.com/mkeiser/TRTabView/

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, my good man.  Sorry for the small condition beforehand.  The [BHTabBar](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bhtabbar) control is nearly perfect, but it is flipped so the tabs are facing upwards.  I'm sure that won't be hard to fix (a couple of CGAffines never hurt anyone).  And if push comes to shove, just style a couple of UIButtons and line them up along a UIToolbar.

For further reading, see [MHTabBarController](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mhtabbarcontroller), [SlidingTabs](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/slidingtabs), and the commercially liscenced [ALTabsView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/altabsview).

Comment: hi thanks but i think its not what i am looking for because it did not give the looks like iPad safari tabs.may be someone else have any idea so i am waiting but thanks for your help i will use this if i did not find any other

Comment: You won't find anything exactly like the iPad tabs no matter how hard you look, buddy.  There's got to be at least some effort on your part.  I'm going to edit this with a few more controls.

Comment: Yes CodaFi you are right but i think if i go to create tabs from scratch it will be very hard and animation of tab when you click on search bar all tab get shifted towards bottom.So creating all this from scratch will be complicated and dont know whether possible.thats why i am looking for some help may be some one else tried already and he can guid me

Comment: If you want to hire someone, [there's a site for that](careers.stackoverflow.com), otherwise yes, there will be mucking around and getting dirty for the first couple weeks.  Just don't give up, and know that nobody here is gonna give you a full implementation without being paid at least $200 and hour.

Comment: ohh i was really unaware that this may too complicated so according to you someone may take up to $2k to get developed??$200 is for one hour??? very costly

Comment: Haha!  That was kind of a joke on my part.  What it means is that this isn't a site to get full code of things, and I've already given you links to examples.  What this site is about is tweakin code and helping with technical problems, in your case, you just want code.